He lacks social grace(s)

(1) He lacks social grace.
(2) He lacks social graces.

Is there any difference in meaning or connotation between these two sentences?
My intuition tells me that (2) is more about social skills.

https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/social_grace    I don't see much difference in considering it as countable or uncountable.

In Britain, at least, there is a fixed phrase, 'the social graces', which some people may have, lack, or 'have no time for'. The phrase means, roughly, 'courtesy or good manners in one's conduct'. Although one finds 'social grace' in dictionaries, my own feeling is that it is much less often used in the UK.

'Grace' is an abstract noun. When it is strictly used as an abstract quality, it is uncountable. "He lacks social grace" means that, in general, he does not display the behaviours considered to make up 'grace'.
However, those individual behaviours are countable and can be referred to as "graces". For example, "social graces", as your examples refer to, could include things like politeness, tact, listening skills, etiquette, table manners etc. Someone with all of those could be described as having "social grace".
This isn't uncommon - many abstract nouns are used countably and uncountably in different contexts. For example, you may have many experiences in your life, but collectively you could be said to have "experience".
